# Show only specific range of pages in pagination?

Tags: php, pagination

I'm doing some paging of mysql results and trying to limit the number of given pages that are listed to a specified variable. It's partially working, but the limit only works at the beginning and end. I believe this is because I need to modify the `for` loop.

Here is what it currently displays.

[image]

[image]
              ^ Should only show 3,4,5,6,7 ^

[image]

PHP:

```
var $max_pages = 4;

$batch = ceil($this->page / $this->links_per_page );
$end = $batch * $this->links_per_page;
if ($end > $this->total_pages) {
    $end = $this->total_pages;
}

$start = 1;

for($i = max($start,$this->page - $this->max_pages);
$i <= min($this->page + $this->max_pages,$end); $i ++) {
    if ($i == $this->page) {
        $prefixActive = '<span class="page_link active">';
        $links .= $prefixActive . "$i" . $suffix;
    } else {
         $links .= ' ' . '<a href="' . $this->php_self . 
         '?page=' . $i . $this->append . '">' .$prefix . $i .
         $suffix. '</a>' . ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is extremely confused. Why `$start = $end - $this->links_per_page + 1;` then actually start with `max($start,$this->page - $this->max_pages)`? The whole problem is you can't seem to make up your mind where you want to start.

Comment: @developerwjk I see what you're saying, `$start` should be 1. I updated the value.

Comment: @developerwjk why you delete your answer? `$i<=$end` works properly until towards the end of the result set, then it starts subtracting the previous pages. By the time it gets to the end only the last page is shown.

Comment: Because I was working on getting it to work exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($this->total_pages > $this->max_pages){ 
    $max_start = max($start,$this->page - $this->max_pages / 2); 
    $start_index = min($this->total_pages - $this->max_pages, $max_start); 
    $end_index = min($this->total_pages, $max_start + $this->max_pages); 
} else { 
    $start_index = 1; 
    $end_index = $this->total_pages; 
} 

for($i = $start_index; $i <= $end_index; $i ++) { 
   if ($i == $this->page) { 
       $prefixActive = '<span class="page_link active">'; 
       $links .= $prefixActive . "$i" . $suffix; 
   } else { 
       $links .= ' ' . '<a href="' . $this->php_self . 
               '?page=' . $i . $this->append . '">' .$prefix . $i . 
               $suffix. '</a>' . ' '; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: It's close, but now shows only 3 pages at beginning and end then 5 in the center (3,4,5,6,7 as expected).

Comment: Even closer but after `max_pages` is reached it begins removing pages until there is only one left at the end.

Comment: Give me the last chance, try again :)

Comment: It works if there are more than `max_pages`, but if there are less it shows negative pages.

Comment: What's the value of $this->links_per_page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67276/discussion-between-hovo-and-eternalhour).